# iPhone project has "My Mac 64-bit"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm working on an iPhone project and somehow the schema has "My Mac 64-bit" and "My Mac 32-bit" in addition to the normal "Simulator 4.3" and "IOS Device".

Is there anyway to remove the "My Mac..." options? It always wants to switch to these when I switch git branches and I end up building without realizing it and get an error. More of an annoyance than anything.

Comment: Still happening in Xcode 4.5. It's things like this that make one wonder how Xcode developer priorities are assigned, certainly not based on developer pain. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens to me every time files get modified outside of Xcode, and Xcode needs to reload the project file. Closing the project and re-opening it always fixes the issue for me.

Comment: That's been my solution so far, but I'm hoping future versions of Xcode offer better git support. I'm not holding my breath though.

Comment: I always open my projects from within Finder to get around this problem.  Browse to your project directory, eg /apps/iOS/iPhone/SingleViewApp.  Double clicking the .xcodeproj file launches the project within Xcode.  I see "Checking DDI Symbols" msg and soon after iPhone device name appears.

Answer (score 34):

Could possibly be something with your xcuserdata folder.

Right-click on the xcodeproj file and select "show package contents."

Make a backup copy of the xcuserdata folder.

Now delete everything inside the xcuserdata folder, and restart xcode.

If causes a problem, then put backup folder back in.

Answer (score 2):

If you are porting your Xcode project from one mac to other then this issue happens most often. You can Try These two resolutions: First one only worked for me:

**Resolution:1**
Open Your project folder > Right Click on Xcode and Select “Show Package Content” Inside there we will get one folder “XcuserData”.> Open the Xcuserdata folder and delete all its content. >Now Launch the Xcode project again, the problem should be fixed now.

if the above resolution is not working then try this one:

**Resolution:2**
open Xcode > clicked on Manage Schemes and then Autocreate Schemes Now > Then select the new scheme in Xcode.

Hope either resolution should work for you.

Comment: Resolution:2 help me!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the beta builds for Xcode 4.2, with regards to their handling of Git repos (confirmed at WWDC with Xcode devs). According to a friend of mine it's been fixed in Xcode 4.2 beta 5, but there are a bunch of issues with that build and you might want to hold off until beta 6.

Comment: Yes, Xcode 4.2 beta 5. This is hearsay, mind you, but according to him they fixed the issues. The guys at WWDC said that it would be fixed before Xcode 4.2 comes out of beta, and until then we just have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Right Click on Xcode project > Show Package contents > xcuserdata > Delete All content 
**Step 2:** Open project > select target > (Project name)Tests > Host Application > select application > allow testing application APIs

Resolved :) Enjoy your Code

Answer (score 0):

I always open my projects from within Finder to get around this problem. Browse to your project directory, eg /apps/iOS/iPhone/SingleViewApp. Double clicking the .xcodeproj file launches the project within Xcode. I see "Checking DDI Symbols" msg and soon after iPhone device name appears.